# Is there any way to describe function parameters first in Haddock?

Tags: haskell, haddock

Typical *Haddock* syntax allow to write something like this

```
-- Initializes local variables so arrays will get defined
--
-- Defer initialization context inside a compound type.
-- 
initialize :: Bool      -- ^ 1st parameter description  
           -> Type      -- ^ 2nd parameter description
           -> [Signal]  -- ^ 3rd parameter description
           -> Structure -- ^ 4th parameter description
           -> Doc       -- ^ result value desription
initialize _ (MachineVector 1 Pointer{}) = equals <+> text "NULL"
```

I want to write it in Java manner, where I have parameters description before function signature. I have more complex signatures, so this approach breaks readability. **Is there any way to write like this?**

```
-- Initializes local variables so arrays will get defined
--
-- Defer initialization context inside a compound type.
-- 
-- ^ 1st parameter description
-- ^ 2nd parameter description
-- ^ 3rd parameter description
-- ^ 4th parameter description
-- ^ result value desription
initialize :: Bool->Type->[Signal]->Structure->Doc       
initialize _ (MachineVector 1 Pointer{}) = equals <+> text "NULL"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking through the Haddock source code, [it looks like no, as function arguments are only extracted from inside types](https://github.com/ghc/haddock/blob/master/haddock-api/src/Haddock/Interface/Create.hs#L342).

Comment: Nice. Couldn't find it at quick glance. Probably, I need to work this out and make pull request.